# hdparm.conf has no effect in 20.04

Tags: hard-drive, 20.04, hdparm, spindown

I recently did a clean install of 20.04 on my server. In 18.04, I could spin down my mechanical drive with this line in hdparm.conf:

```
/dev/sda {
    spindown_time = 25
}
```

Now, the config file doesn't appear to have any effect. I can still set the spindown manually:

`sudo hdparm -S 25 /dev/sda`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There is no way to upgrade (clean install). You either upgrade, or reinstall.

Comment: True, I tried to fit in the information that I was running 18.04 before and it didn't come out right. Edited for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During recent reboots hdparm.conf seems to work again. Maybe an update fixed this, I haven't changed anything on my system.